# Dose this operator have what meaning?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-shift

I'm Korean stduent.
I have seen some code a few days ago.
There was unknown operator >>> , <<<
so, I have tried to search that operator has what meaning.
but I couldn't find out. 
Can you explain for me?
Thank you.

Comment: What language ?

Comment: javascript.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the language but it's *usually* a shift-with-wrap-around operator.

That's like a left and right bit-shift operator but the bits get "wrapped around" when they go off one side.

For example:

```
10110110 >>  2 = 00101101
10110110 >>> 2 = 10101101
```

Comment: i don't understand....  in javascript,                                                                         var a = parseInt(10110110 ,2);                                                                                            a >> 101101 // 45                                                                                                                                     a >>> 10110 // 22

Comment: @Hyunsoo Each language treats them differently. JavaScript's [`>>>` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) is fully documented.